# Can I prune an avocado plant that is almost 50 inches tall?

Tags: avocado

I should state from the start that I have no experience in gardening.

A little more than a year ago I've decided to plant an avocado seed and it grew really tall (almost 50 inches). Now I want to transfer it to a new much bigger pot because this one is obviously way too small and while reading how to do it I've learned that a plant should be pruned to become bushy. But all articles that I've read were referring to short plants that are about to be cut, no one was writing about bad cases such as mine. So my question is - isn't it too late to prune my plant? And how should I do it? Should I cut the most part of the plant so it becomes 12 inches tall? Or should I cut a little bit and repeat this process several times with some interval?

I also feel sorry to cut the new fresh leaves at the top because they look very beautiful compared to the lower ones.

[image]
[image]
[image]